Notification sound not working in Flutter release APK, but works in debug mode
I’m facing an issue with notifications in my Flutter app. I’m using the flutter_local_notifications package to schedule local notifications and play a custom sound with the notification. The sound plays fine when I run the app in debug mode on my device, but when I install the release APK, only the notification shows up and no sound plays.
File placement: I placed my custom sound file (my_sound.m4a and .aiff) in the android/app/src/main/res/raw/ folder.
I’ve referenced the sound like RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('my_sound')

The original sound files were .m4a and .aiff. I tried converting them to .mp3 and .wav formats, but still no change. I’ve configured the notification channel correctly and set playSound: true in the AndroidNotificationDetails.

I added the exact alarm permission in the AndroidManifest.xml.I’ve ensured that battery optimization is turned off on the device. I’ve requested the exact alarm permission from the user when needed.

The sound works perfectly in debug mode.

However, when I build a release APK and install it on my device, the notification shows up but there is no sound.

Changing the sound file format to .wav, .mp3, and .m4a — no success.

Rebuilding the APK and installing it again.

Checking battery optimizations to ensure the app isn't being killed in the background.

I’m unsure why the notification sound works in debug mode but not in the release APK. Could it be an issue with notification channels, permissions, or a configuration problem in release mode? Any help would be greatly appreciated!


